# Ajax Control Toolkit and custom HttpModules

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, httpmodule

I'm creating an ASP.NET application (.NET 2.0) with C# and I'm using the AJAX Control Toolkit.

To ensure security I'm using a custom `HttpModule` to verifiy the user credentials on each request. In the developement envirenment everything works as expected, but in the production environment some of the controls don't work, like the CalendarExtender for example. However, if I disable the `HttpModule`, the controls start working again.

Is there any relation between the Ajax Control Toolkit and custom `HttpModules`?

If not, can any one please explain how to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, i have just moved the code wich control the acces from the
PostAcquireRequestState event handler to the PostRequestHandlerExecute one.